# How can I achieve this typographic result in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am wonder if this could be achieved in photoshop with a plugin or with what.

It seems for me like the text is not only justified. Every single line appears to be scaled in relation with the length to adapt to the full width of the text container.

Any help! Thank you in advance ;)

[image]

Comment: Use guide lines... increase the size of your texts, align your words. No, there's probably no plugins for this. It could be even better to do this in Illustrator actually.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57620/aligning-letters-wrong-appears-more-right

Comment: Generally, you adjust each line as needed by hand.

Answer (score 2):

You can either uses guidelines or you can use a square with 50% opacity and fit these words inside the square. Make every word its own text object for more control and align them. When dealing with text, illustrator is a better option.