# Logo design: Suggestions for how to apply proportions of logomark and logotype in horizontal layout

Tags: logo, design-principles, layout

I have been playing around a bit with logo design as of late, and I'm curious if anyone has any suggestions or can recommend approaches for defining the **sizing** of a logomark when juxtaposed with corresponding logotype in a horizontal layout? (See a diagram below.) This is more of a design theory/principle-type question related to ratios and proportions and I'm curious, for example, how might one apply the golden ratio in this context or perhaps a ratio more intrinsically related to the specific composition of the logo itself? I'm interested in any sort of feedback from folks who spend time with logo design, and what might typically inform these kinds of decisions for you (in no way limited to the golden ratio.) Thanks for any insight here!

[image: Logomark/logotype proportions diagram]

Comment: Is A really a circle? If not, there's pretty much no very standard way

Comment: @ZachSaucier In my current case, A (the logomark) is indeed a circle- how would that impact your own decision making with sizing relative to the logotype?

Comment: It's mostly an optical thing. Without seeing *actual* artwork it's difficult to provide anything. I mean that circle *could* be heavy and overwhelming.. or it could be wispy and light... so...

Comment: I think the Golden Ratio, while it works in some contexts, is not suitable for something like this.  Getting the right balance between a logo and text is subjective. I don't think you should follow some rule or formula for this. It's dependent on what the logo actually is and the length of the word, font and weight choice, etc. There are just too many variables. I'd suggest you adjust it until it looks pleasing to you.

Comment: [Relevant](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/57712/23061)

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback- I figured it might ultimately be a more subjective question, going by eye based on the composition of the logo, but just wondered if folks used any kinds of techniques to guide the decision making.